# How to trust Frontend Facebook Login

Tags: javascript, facebook, laravel-5, facebook-login

Quick short background

I'm building a **standalone web app** using Angular JS 1.5. This **web app** makes usage of a API built with **Laravel 5.2** (no sessions, just JWT Tokens and REST calls). Using Laravel-Socialite, I managed to make the following structure. It works nice and all, but we kind of have a overload of redirects.

[image]

The Button calls a **/facebook** route that invokes the Socialite magic box which leads to redirect to the Facebook Page for authorization.

After I achieved this, I noticed that a Facebook Login **LOOKS** a lot more of a **front-end** task than a **back-end** one. It's just about helping the user quickly **sign up** using Facebok available data or **sign in** without a password.

### The Problem

Socialite makes usage of my **Facebook App Secret**, not to mention that it's a known environment server operation, while a Front-end we may never trust. Here is what I managed to achieve using JavaScript SDK (with AngularJS).

[image]

On a first-time access, I can get that information and **sign up the user** and automatically sign him in. But the problem lies on a existing user.

In this case, technically I can use the **response.email** information that Facebook gave me and make a request to my API to make a login without a password. But can I really do it? How do I make sure the request is being made because Facebook authorized it? After Facebook replies to my Web App, what is a secure way to tell my server that it can issue a JWT Token to that email?

### Conclusion

Do I make the three-step redirection (Web App → Server API → Facebook) to sign in / authenticate a user using Facebook or is there something I'm missing here that could be the key to transferring this responsibility to the front-end (and avoiding a 3-step-redirection)?